# pdfmake - remove header margin from pages > 1

Tags: header, margin, pdfmake

I'm using this code for header in my generated pdf,
but even though the header is removed for pages after the first page, the top margin is still reserved by `docDefinition.pageMargins = [10,120,10,70]` 
Is there a way to remove the top margin on pages > 1?

```
docDefinition.header = function(page, pages) { 
                if(page>1) return {};

                return {
                    columns: [
                        {                       
                            image:  logo,
                            height: 90      
                        },
                        {
                            stack: [
                                {text: 'Some title'},
                                {text: 'Some other row'}

                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    height:100, 
                    margin: [10,10],    
                }
            }
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this post while searching for the exact same thing. https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/368 seems to be an open issue.

Comment: If the header is only in the first page, you can set your regular global page margin and add the header as the first element in the document content. If the header needs a different top margin, you can displace it using a negative top margin. Similar for left and right margins.

Answer (score 3):

```
header: (currentPage, pageCount) => {
  if (currentPage != 1) {
    {
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'Header text',
                fontSize: 15,
                style: { alignment: 'left', color: '#3c3c3c' },
                bold: true,
            },
        ]
    },
    // return header;
  }
},
```

you can check it with **currentPage != 1**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can display header/footer for specific pages in PDFMake

**Simple Example**

```
header: function(page) { 
          if (page != 1) 
                  return {text: 'Other page footer'}
              else
                      return {text: 'Page 1 footer'}
}
```

**Complex Example**

```
footer: function(page) { 
          if (page != 1){
             return { columns: [
          [{
            canvas: [
              {
                type: 'line',
                x1: 0,
                y1: 5,
                x2: 510,
                y2: 5,
                lineWidth: 1,
              },
            ],
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [50, -10, 0, 0],
          },
          {
            style: 'footer',
            text: [
              'This is a demo footer -',
              {
                text: 'For PDFMake',
                color: '#ed3833',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            canvas: [
              {
                type: 'line',
                x1: 0,
                y1: 5,
                x2: 510,
                y2: 5,
                lineWidth: 0.8,
              },
            ],
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [50, -2, 0, 0],
          },
          {
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [527, 5, 0, 0],
            fontSize: 8,
            text: ['© 2021'],
          },]
             ]}         
          }
        },
```

[image: Screenshot]